# configurable products and simple products properties

Tags: configurable-product

I removed a configurable product but its simple products remained in that category. Is this how it works?Shouldn’t the properties of the parent determine the properties of the simple products beneath it?

Comment: Welcome To SE. Please add tags for the magento version you are using

Answer (score 0):

Simple and configurable products are different and separate products.

vendors can sell simple product individually if they want.

or they can sell same simple product with bundle or group product.

Its just mapping and association with some attribute so we can mapp simple product with configurable product.

and if you added configurable product in some category then its not compulsory to add simple product to same category.( because most of the associate simple products are **not visible individual** )